# How to create admin custom from using UI in Magento 2 using layout?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent

- I want to create admin custom from using UI component
- But I am not able to understand to structure, can someone please
  explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to understand how works UI components in magento is research magento code and try write your own form, for example in module Magento_Cms - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml (note: use syntax like in magento 2.1 for compatibility with all versions magento 2 https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml). Also you can check tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCgi2-ZB7fA. Hope it will help you, if you will have any questions you can ask me.